# PDF Preview on Button click in angular

Tags: html, angular, base64

How can i preview Pdf while using Base64 data:

Html code

.ts code

let file = new Blob([byte64String],{type:'application/pdf'});
this.pdfSourceUrl = URL.createObjectUrl(file);

on preview i am getting blank page and in url i am getting "blob:https://localhost:4500/983ec5525-45re776-..........**encriptionbase64data**. what i need actual pdf file instead of blank page. in url preview i am getting Base64 encrypted data.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/base64) library by passing the base64 string for your PDF file.

Comment: Alexandru first i have forbidden to use third party library second i have display this in modal popup